# Merge two visual studio .resx files

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012

I have two large resource files and I have to merge them. There may be some Name attributes which are the same in both files

```
<data name="SomeResource" xml:space="preserve">
    <value> The resource value </value>
</data>
```

How to get all the resources names which are the same? If there are some entries with equal value it's not problem, but equal names is a problem.

Comment: Have you tried with some file comparison softwares.. They'll let you know exact lines matching..

Comment: Take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37022/Solving-the-resx-Merge-Problem). It might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a small console application to get all the duplicate resource names:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //replace with your strongly typed resource classes
        var rm1 = MyApplication.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
        var rm2 = MyApplication.Properties.Resources1.ResourceManager;

        var rs1 = rm1.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        var rs2 = rm2.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);

        var result = from re1 in rs1.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                     join re2 in rs2.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                         on re1.Key equals re2.Key
                     select new { re1, re2 };

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.Write("Key with name \"{0}\" is present in ", 
                item.re1.Key);
            Console.WriteLine("both files (\"{0}\" and \"{1}\")", 
                item.re1.Value, item.re2.Value);
        }
    }
}
```